# Is there any way to return value in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder if I can return value in list comprehension like

```
[return role_ for role_ in self.roles if role.name==parameter]
```

Of course it doesn't work. At the moment I had to use classic for loop

```
for role_ in self.roles:
    if role_.name == parameter:
        return role_
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a 1-liner equivalent of your "classic for loop"?

Comment: No, because a list comprehension is there to produce a list.

Comment: Exactly. My code above is "unreachable".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a generator expression:

```
return next((role_ for role_ in self.roles if role_.name == parameter), None)
```

This will return the first matching `role_` value, or `None` if there is no such value.

You can't use a list comprehension, no, because you are *not producing a list*.

Answer (score 12):

No. The purpose of a list comprehension is to build a list, not to save lines of code.

Since you do not want a list as the result, a list comprehension is the wrong tool for the job. A loop is perfectly fine.

Comment: Okay, so that was my miss understanding of list comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing would be a calling `next` with a generator expression:

```
return next(role_ for role_ in self.roles if role_.name==parameter)
```